# angularjs directive updated regardless of control variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

First of all, sorry about the title of the post, I couldn´t find a better way to explain the problem.

I have a really simple html page with some directives which are displayed or not depending on some control variables. I prepared a reduced version in a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/danaya/pg7ssq9t/4/).

What I want here is:
  1. display only search button
  2. when I click search, display also a note 'searching...' while I do some I/O operations
  3. when I finish those operations, remove note 'searching...' and display a list of values and also the search button.

What I'm getting is:
  1. display search button
  2. when I click search, list is displayed with the button, no 'searching...' and also before I finished my I/O operations.

This is the main html and the js:

```
<div>
  <list ng-if="vm.isList()"></list>
  <search ng-if="vm.isSearch()"></search>
  <div ng-if="vm.isSearching()">Searching...</div>
</div>

angular
  .module("app", [])
  .controller('MyController', MyController)
  .directive('list', list)
  .directive('search', search);

function MyController() {

  var vm = this;
  var isList = false;
  var isSearch = true;
  var isSearching = false;

  vm.isList = function() {
    return isList;
  }
  vm.isSearch = function() {
    return isSearch;
  }

  vm.isSearching = function() {
    return isSearching;
  }

  vm.search = function() {
    isSearching = true;

    for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        total += i;
      }
      console.info(j + ': ' + total);
    }

    isList = true;
    isSearching = false;
  }

}

function list() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    template: '<ul><li>item1</li><li>item2</li><li>item3</li></ul>'
  }
}

function search() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    replace: true,
    template: '<button type="button" ng-click="vm.search()">search</button>'
  }
}
```

Any ideas?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is OK. Your emulation of 'operation' is not. Cause most time-cost operations are usually async.

```
$timeout(function() {
    isList = true;
    isSearching = false;
}, 2000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/avL8g1jv/

(
if you have time-cost sync operation like for `(i = 0; i < 999999)` you need first set view variable and then call this time-cost operation using `$timeout`-- this way angular will update your html, and after your costly operarion will run. )